# How to remove/collapse/hide a line if a field is empty

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, address

I’m utilizing AMPScript to create variables for an address block in our email.

My question is:  How do I make a line disappear or “collapse” in the email body, if a field in the Data Extension is empty?

For my scenario, I just want the line where a company name should be, to collapse if a customer does not have a company name in that field.  I’m pulling data from one Data Extension.

I basically tried to use the IIF function, with no success.  You’ll see that in my code below.

```
%%[ 

Var @firstname, @lastname, @company, @shipaddress1, @shipaddress2, @city, @state, @zipcode, @cusid
set @firstname = FirstName
Set @lastname = LastName
Set @company = Company
Set @shipaddress1 = ShipAddress1
Set @shipaddress2 = ShipAddress2
Set @city = City
Set @state = State
Set @zipcode = ZipCode
Set @cusid = CUSID

]%%
%%=IIF(EMPTY(@company)," ",@company)=%%
```

**Body of email:**

```
%%=v(@firstname)=%% %%=v(@lastname)=%%<br/>
%%=v(@company)=%%<br/>
%%=v(@shipaddress1)=%% %%=v(@shipaddress2)=%%<br/>
%%=v(@city)=%%, %%=v(@state)=%% %%=v(@zipcode)=%%<br/>
<strong>CUSID:</strong> %%=v(@cusid)=%%<br/><br/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this -- utilizing the [**AttributeValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/) and [**concat()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/concat/) functions:

```
%%[ 

var @firstname, @lastname, @company, @shipaddress1, @shipaddress2, @city, @state, @zipcode, @cusid
set @firstname = AttributeValue("FirstName")
Set @lastname = AttributeValue("LastName")
Set @company = AttributeValue("Company")
Set @shipaddress1 = AttributeValue("ShipAddress1")
Set @shipaddress2 = AttributeValue("ShipAddress2")
Set @city = AttributeValue("City")
Set @state = AttributeValue("State")
Set @zipcode = AttributeValue("ZipCode")
Set @cusid = AttributeValue("CUSID")

]%%
%%=iif(not empty(@firstname),@firstname,"")=%%%%=iif(not empty(@lastname),concat(" ",@lastname),"")=%%<br/>
%%=iif(not empty(@company),concat(@company,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@shipaddress1),concat(@shipaddress1,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@shipaddress2),concat(@shipaddress2,"<br/>"),"")=%%
%%=iif(not empty(@city),concat(@city,", "),"")=%% %%=iif(not empty(@state),@state,"")=%% %%=iif(not empty(@zipcode),concat(@zipcode,"<br/>"),"")=%%
<strong>CUSID:</strong> %%=v(@cusid)=%%<br/><br/>
```

You may need to fiddle around with the City/State/Zip line based on what you know about your source data.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm!  Really appreciate your help @Adam Spriggs  I've come across many of your answers here when doing Marketing Cloud problem searches and for the most part, I've been able to figure things out because of your answers.  Glad I jumped in!

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Would you checking the check-mark beside my answer?  I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to do so.  As you can see, still learning how to use StackExchange properly.  Thanks again!